# Illustrator CS5 crashes when I open fonts menu

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

Does anyone know of a way to fix this? Googling reveals only solutions for older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be one or a combination of the following.

**A** Too many fonts activated/installed
**B** Corrupt font(s) (if WYSIWYG menus are on)
**C** Corrupt system or application font cache
**D** Corrupt application preferences

**A is simple: Slim down your font selection.** Big OpenType families and pi fonts are good candidates, if you're not using them.

**B can be more difficult.** If you've recently installed anything, that's a good place to start. It could be a file that was fine at one point and has become corrupted, though. If you have a font manager like Suitcase, FontExplorer or something you might be able to use the built in utility to diagnose the problem.

**C isn't tough, you just have to know what to delete** for the app in question. Adobe has a global font cache for all it's apps, iirc. If you're on OS X, it has another. Your font manager may be able to clear this out for you (FontExplorer does). You can also dump the cache files via the Finder or Terminal in OS X.

**D is easy, but you lose settings.** Back up the prefs file in case you find it wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling any recent fonts you may have installed. Otherwise I would suggest reinstalling Illustrator and seeing how that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and I just solved it by going to ***Preferences > Type***, and then changing my **font preview size to "small"**.  It has stopped crashing for me.  Hope this helps you!